# how to get applicationpath from masterpage code page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

If it is a normal page I can use

```
public static string GetRootPathJS(Page page)
{
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    string strApp = page.Request.ApplicationPath;
    if (strApp == "/") strApp = "";

    strBuilder.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
    strBuilder.AppendFormat("rootPath=\"" + strApp + "\";");
    strBuilder.Append("</script>");

    return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

In pageonload method just call

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "root", GetRootPathJS(this));
```

After this I can call rootPath directly in client side using javascript. But in masterpage code page there is no ClientScript reference. How to get rootpath in masterpage code page. I also tried to get rootpath from children page, however, the javascript in masterpage can not find rootpath defined in children page.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly your trying to get the root path in Javascript?

If so you can use the following on the masterpage.master

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>';
</script>
```

Comment: Yea, I want to use it in Javascript. I just tried your code, in local environment it works, but in remote server it does not. In local, all my web page is in UI folder, so the baseUrl=/UI/, in remote server since I set UI to be the website path, the baseUrl=/, the AjaxPage I am trying to call is under UI/AjaxPage folder, which I don't understand why it does not work in remote server. $.post(rootPath+"AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx"....) Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried alerting or logging the `rootPath+"AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx"` just to make sure its a valid url?

Comment: rootPath+"AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx"=/AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx, which is correct, but the ajax does not work. If it runs in local, rootPath+"AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx"=/UI/AjaxPages/UserStatus.aspx, however, in remote server the root is UI folder. Any idea?